$L_2$ convergence of functions under weak convergence of measures.
Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure on a compact interval on $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $f_n:X \to \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of uniformly bounded continuous functions converging to $f$ in $L_2$ under $\mathbb{P}$, that is, $$
\mathbb{E}(f_n-f)^2 \to 0.
$$Now let $\mathbb{P}_n$ be a sequence of measure that converges weakly to $\mathbb{P}$, does it hold that under the sequence of measure, that $$
\mathbb{E}_n (f_n-f)^2 \to 0?
$$My attempt is that simply decompose $\mathbb{E}_n = \mathbb{E} + (\mathbb{E}_n - \mathbb{E})$. Then $\mathbb{E}(f_n-f)^2\to 0$ by assumption and uniform boundedness of $(f_n-f)^2$. Now $0\leq (\mathbb{E_n}-\mathbb{E})(f_n-f)^2\leq (\mathbb{E_n}-\mathbb{E})(4\max{(\max_n f_n,f)}) \to 0$ by assumption on the convergence of measure, hence it holds that $$\mathbb{E}_n (f_n-f)^2 \to 0.$$

Your approach does not work. Indeed, here is a counterexample: Let $X = [0, 1]$, $\mathbb{P} = \delta_1$, $f_n = x^n$, and $f = 1_{\{1\}}$. Then obviously $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{P})$ (in fact, $f_n = f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{P})$). $f_n$ are uniformly bounded by $1$. Now, let $\mathbb{P}_n = \delta_{e^{-\frac{1}{2n}}}$. Since $e^{-\frac{1}{2n}} \to 1$, we have $\mathbb{P}_n \to \mathbb{P}$ weakly. However,
$$\mathbb{E}_n(f_n - f)^2 = [(e^{-\frac{1}{2n}})^n - 0]^2 = e^{-1} \not\to 0$$
